# How to copy the returned token by strtok

Tags: c, strtok, strcpy

So basically I don't know how to work with this command well, I searched around the forums and could understand how to print the string and using the pointers but I want to divide the string and save all the tokens in different variables.

I'm trying to do something like this

```
char s[20],*pt,name[10];
pt=strtok(s," ");
```

Now I want to save the first toke on the name string, but I get errors on the terminal and the only thing that works (passing only the pointer) gets me 1 letter only.

- `name=pt;` doesnt work.
- `*(name)=*pt` works but gets me only 1 letter.

The complete code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
FILE *f=fopen("tarefas.txt","r");
char s[50];

typedef struct{
char nome[20];
int trab;
int acab;
} tarefa;


int i=0,*dias;
tarefa *v;
char *pt;

v=(tarefa *) malloc(sizeof(tarefa));
dias=(int *) malloc(sizeof(int));


while(fgets(s,50,f)){
pt= strtok(s," ");

v[i].nome=s; //doesnt work

int t=strlen(v[i].nome);
v[i].nome[t]='\0';

printf("%s\n",s);

}
```

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok on the web

Comment: I added the code I have btw

Comment: You need to copy the contents of the string with `strcpy`, or, safer, with `strncpy`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Answer (score 1):

> *`name=pt`; doesnt work.*

and

> *`v[i].nome=s; //doesnt work`*

They are not supposed to *work*, anyway. Array names are not modifiable lvaues and hence are not assignable in C.

To copy a string, you should be using [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy).

Something like

```
 strcpy(v[i].nome,s);
```

should do the job just fine.

That said, you should check

- For the non-NULL return from `strtok()` before performing any operation with the returned pointer.
- `strlen()` of the returned token and check against the destination buffer size before copying to prevent buffer overflow.
- [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: @JoãoGomes why not? Did you try it?

Comment: I'm just dumb sry, first year not izi :/

Comment: The source is `pt`, the destination is `v[i].nome`, so `strncpy(v[i].nome, pt, 19); v[i].nome[19] = '\0';`. But check that `pt` is non-`NULL` before doing that!